# What is the proper way how to fire event on start and finish of the complex drawing using KanvaJS?

Tags: konvajs

I am drawing a complex graphic on canvas using KonvaJS library. Execution takes few seconds and I want to  monitor progress on user screen, but I can't make work functions like:

```
layer.on('draw', () => {
  console.log('Draw finished')
})
```

What is the proper way how to fire event on start and finish of the drawing using KanvaJS?

Here is a test code where console.log('Draw finished') is not executed

```
var stage = new Konva.Stage({
  container: 'canvas-container',   // id of HTML div container 
  width: 1000,
  height: 500,
});

function drawGrid(){
    let layerMPE = new Konva.Layer();
    let pxMax = stage.width();
    let pyMax = stage.height();
    let res = 10;
    
    for (let px=0; px < pxMax; px += res){
        for (let py=0; py < pyMax; py += res){
            
            let rect = new Konva.Rect({
                x: px,
                y: py,
                width: res,
                height: res,
                fill: 'red'
              });
            layerMPE.add(rect);
        }
    }
    
    stage.add(layerMPE);
    layerMPE.draw();
    
    layerMPE.on('draw', () => {
      console.log('Draw finished')
    });
}
    
drawGrid();
```

Comment: Can you clarify why do you need this? Do you want to measure execution time of `layer.draw()`?

Comment: I want show progress of 
- loading image to stage,
drawing of the stage - indicator that shows div with loader gif and then hides it when drawing is finished.

Comment: Events:  
1. Kanva: set stage  
2. start calculation  
3. ... show loader gif  
4. Kanva: load big image  
5. calculation loop start, Kanva draw something on each iteration  
6. ... hide loader gif

Comment: Aside from images, all other shape drawing should happen so fast that a progress bar is not needed.  Change your layer.draw() to layer.batchdraw() which gives optimum layer redrawing. If you have a grid then draw on a separate layer, cache it, and you will not have the 'weight' of refreshing it because it will not change. A progress indicator could be appropriate if you are loading a large quantity of images and in that case you can include the progress update logic in the onLoad() event func for each image. So in summary, I do not think that you need the events you think you might.